# Github Pull Request Builder - Test this please not trigger build

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, pull-request

I've configured the Github Pull Request Builder following the instructions in [README](https://github.com/janinko/ghprb)

It seems work via cron ONLY - it runs the job every hour. However, directly commenting "test this please" or push to repository does not trigger the build. I've a 'bot' jenkins-user as admin in my repository. I've also enabled github-webhook and /jenkins/ghprbhook under **Webhooks & Services**

I want to know how the PR Builder react to the "test this please" comment.. is there a way I can monitor it?

Comment: Some pitfalls I've experienced and fixed: https://github.com/ruslo/polly/wiki/Jenkins-%28build-bot,-PR%29

Comment: @ruslo , I am really really thankful to you ! :) It works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, if you follow the instruction and setup the Pull Request Builder, it's a cron.

For every periodic run, it detects if there's a new commit or "test this please" comment after last check. If yes, then it will trigger the build.

Note that, GHPRB will create a temp branch that merges your PR code to default branch. And it will alert you if there's conflict in the code.

Comment: I just want to add one bit of clarification, even though this is an old question/answer.  The plugin doesn't actually create a temp branch.  It just takes advantage of the fact that GitHub creates a temp branch when you create a pull request that shows if the PR is able to merge without conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's `retest this please`
2. If the regular push to the repo does not work, the PR part won't work as well. In my experience the regular push was easier to get working
3. Are you sure that your account on GitHub can push to the repo and that you have set the correct endpoint for the hook on GitHub?